# Marketing Cloud - Export/View Lifetime Email Behavior For Single Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, subscriber

I'd like to see lifetime event history for one subscriber... emails delivered, emails opened, emails clicked, unsubscribe event, etc. Is there anything in SFMC that would allow me to see this information at the subscriber level?

The closest I can get is this, which only displays the last 90 days:

[image: Subscriber History]

If I could get this same information but for a subscriber's lifetime, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to query the system data views to do this. Unfortunately the system data views only contain the last 180 days of activity. To extend this you would have to contact support.